# Best practice to synchronize UserDefaults via iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, userdefaults

I have an app with various settings and state saved in UserDefaults, and I want to automatically synchronize them across multiple devices. However, every approach I've tried so far has resulted in losing the latest settings at some point. For example, when a user is offline for a few minutes, or when another device with older UserDefaults data launches and uploads the old data, causing devices with newer data to download the outdated information.

I have tried using Zephyr, a Swift package for synchronizing UserDefaults with iCloud, as well as DefaultsCloudSync, a Swift file from GitHub that serves a similar purpose. I have also created my own class based on DefaultsCloudSync, but all attempts have yielded the same results.

I would like to know how other apps deal with this issue or if there is a "perfect" solution available. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

This is my custom iCloud service class (not my proudest code):

```
class iCloudBackupService: NSObject {

class func manualUpload() -> Result<Void, Error> {
    do {
        let defaultsDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()
        let cloudStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default
        for (key, obj) in defaultsDictionary {
            cloudStore.set(obj, forKey: key as String)
        }
        
        // Get the keys that need to be removed
        let keysToRemove = cloudStore.dictionaryRepresentation.keys.filter { key in
            !defaultsDictionary.keys.contains(key)
        }

        // Remove the keys from the dictionary
        for key in keysToRemove {
            cloudStore.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
        
        cloudStore.synchronize()
        let excludedUserDefaults = UserDefaults()
        excludedUserDefaults.set(Date(), forKey: "cloudBackupLastUpload")
        print("Manually Updated iCloud")
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil);
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey: "icloudLastBackupDate")
        UserDefaults.standard.set("manual", forKey: "icloudLastBackupTrigger")
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateiCloudFromUserDefaults(notification:)), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
        
        return .success(())
    } catch let error {
        return .failure(error)
    }
}

class func manualRestore() -> Result<Void, Error> {
    do {
        // Your code to execute if localDate is older than or equal to cloudDate.
        stop()
        let iCloudDictionary = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.dictionaryRepresentation
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        for (key, obj) in iCloudDictionary {
            userDefaults.set(obj, forKey: key as String)
        }
        userDefaults.synchronize()
        let excludedUserDefaults = UserDefaults()
        excludedUserDefaults.set(Date(), forKey: "cloudBackupLastLocalUpdate")
        print("Manually Updated local UserDefaults")
        if userDefaults.bool(forKey: "iCloudBackup") == true {
            start()
        }
        return .success(())
    } catch let error {
        return .failure(error)
    }
}



class func start() {
    // Note: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification is sent only upon a change received from iCloud, not when your app (i.e., the same instance) sets a value.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateUserDefaultsFromiCloud(notification:)), name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateiCloudFromUserDefaults(notification:)), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    
    print("CloudBackup service started")
    print("Enabled automatic synchronization of NSUserDefaults and iCloud.")
}

@objc class func updateUserDefaultsFromiCloud(notification: NSNotification?) {
    // Prevent loop of notifications by removing our observer before updating UserDefaults
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)

    let iCloudDictionary = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.dictionaryRepresentation
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    // Update UserDefaults with values from iCloud
    for (key, obj) in iCloudDictionary {
        userDefaults.set(obj, forKey: key as String)
    }
    userDefaults.synchronize()

    // Increment iCloud session automatic download times
    iCloudSessionAutomaticDownloadTimes += 1

    print("iCloudBackupService: Automatic Download. Times this Session: \(iCloudSessionAutomaticDownloadTimes)")

    // Re-enable UserDefaultsDidChangeNotification notifications
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateUserDefaultsFromiCloud(notification:)), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
}


@objc class func updateiCloudFromUserDefaults(notification: NSNotification?) {
    // Remove the observer before adding it again
    
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    
    let defaultsDictionary = UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()
    let cloudStore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default
    var printKey = ""
    var keyIsRemovable = false
    
    
    for (key, obj) in defaultsDictionary {
        cloudStore.set(obj, forKey: key)
        printKey = key
        keyIsRemovable = false
    }

    // Get the keys that need to be removed
    let keysToRemove = cloudStore.dictionaryRepresentation.keys.filter { key in
        !defaultsDictionary.keys.contains(key)
    }

    // Remove the keys from the dictionary
    for key in keysToRemove {
        cloudStore.removeObject(forKey: key)
        printKey = key
        keyIsRemovable = true
    }

    // let iCloud know that new or updated keys, values are ready to be uploaded
    cloudStore.synchronize()

    // Increment iCloud session automatic upload times
    iCloudSessionAutomaticUploadTimes += 1

    print("iCloudBackupService: Automatic Upload. Times this Session: \(iCloudSessionAutomaticUploadTimes) Current Object: \(printKey). KeyIsRemovable: \(keyIsRemovable)" )


    // Add the observer again
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateiCloudFromUserDefaults(notification:)), name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
}



class func stop() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification, object: nil);
    print("CloudBackup service stopped")
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UserDefaults.didChangeNotification, object: nil);
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.didChangeExternallyNotification, object: nil);
}
```

}

Comment: I would assume many apps that needs to share settings store them in iCloud only without involving UserDefaults

Comment: That would be possible. I tried CoreData but I thought it’s not necessary for my app.

Comment: No I meant iCloud only and no local storage in any form.

Comment: Ah okay, that’s a possibility. But do you know how it handles when the device is offline?